# Replace embedded object in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I created a command button in sheet and when user click on that button there will be a form appear with 2 command buttons. The first button to show the embedded file, the second one to replace it. This is the code.

```
Private Sub firstbutton_Click()

Sheet3.OLEObjects("Source").Activate

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceBtn_Click()

Dim vFile As Variant

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Find file to insert")
If LCase(vFile) = "false" Then

    Unload Me

Exit Sub
End If

Sheet3.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=vFile, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True,IconFileName:=vFile


Unload Me

End Sub
```

The problem is, how to replace the embedded file with a new file and rename it as "Source" since the first button will get the name "Source".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to replace the contents of an embedded object (although I could be wrong), so you will probably have delete the existing object before adding the new one and renaming it. If it were a linked object, you could change what the link points to.

```
Sheet3.OLEObjects.Item("Source").Delete

Dim newObject As OLEObject
Set newObject = Sheet3.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=vFile, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:=vFile)

newObject.Name = "Source"
```

Comment: The code wors fine, but when i tried to save, the was a problem. I cannot save the file.

Comment: What happens when you try to save, does it give any indication what the problem is?

Comment: "Error were detected while saving. Microsoft excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features" This is the error message

Comment: I changed the Delete statement in the code slightly, in case this was the problem. I don't get the error you are describing. Have you tried closing the file (without saving) and trying again? And is there any more info that you can get from the error message box?

Comment: There is an option to repair the file after the error box. The repair also does not work. Can you send me the file

Comment: My file is just a dummy file containing the above code and not much else, I don't think there's any point in sending it to you! It sounds like your file has got corrupted somehow. I would suggest starting again from the last time you saved. If you are worried about losing data then you could make a copy of the saved file and use that, while keeping the unsavable file open.

Comment: The problem is when I removed the object inserted, I can save the file. When I add again and try to save, It show the same error. I already tried on another computer and it gave the same error. I think the problem is the object inserted.

Comment: Have you tried selecting different objects to insert? What type of object are you trying to insert? Have you tried inserting an object manually (without using code) after deleting the existing object?

Comment: Yes, I already did that. The type of file is pdf file. When I inserted the file manually, there is nothing wrong. From what I notice, when I inserted the file manually, the formula bar show that  =EMBED("AcroExch.Document.11","") but when I insert using the code, the formula is =EMBED("Acrobat Document",""). Is this something related to the error? Sorry for asking too much.

Comment: I don't know, I have been unable to replicate the error. Anything you can do to describe the issue in more detail and narrow down the issue to be as simple as possible would be helpful. For example, have you tried copying the code that creates and renames the object to a new workbook to see if that will let you save it? Have you tried saving after the object has been created, but before renaming it? Have you checked whether there is only one object named "Source" after the new object has been created?

Comment: I have tried everything you said. Nothing works. I don't know what is wrong with the object.

Comment: So copying the code and running it in a new workbook (i.e. just running this: `Set newObject = Sheet3.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=vFile, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:=vFile)`) also corrupts that file? Does it work for other file/object types (not pdfs)?

Comment: now I know what is wrong with the code. The problem is the icon file name. When I add the file, I does not show the pdf logo but when I try to add jpeg format, it automatically show the jpeg icon. I tried to set display as icon false and It works properly (I can save the file). now I want to know the icon file name for the pdf because it did not automatically display the pdf file when set IconFileName:=vfile.

Comment: (I think) By default it will display the default pdf viewer's icon (for pdfs) when `DisplayAsIcon:=True`. Setting `IconFileName` then overrides the default **if it contains an icon**, so you should link to an [icon file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) containing the icon you want. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195728.aspx) for more info.